# Reversing a file name based on delimiter then truncating part

Tags: powershell

I need to rename many hundreds of files to follow a new naming convention, but I'm having awful trouble. This really needs to be scripted in powershell or VBS so we can automate the task in a regular basis.

Original File Name
Monday,England.txt

New File Name
EnglanMo

Convention Rules:

1. The file name is reversed around the delimiter (,) to England,Monday and then truncated to 6/2 char

   Englan,Mo
2. The Delimiter is then removed

   englanmo.txt

Say we had Wednesday,Spain.txt spain being 5 char, this is not subject to any reduction
SpainWe.txt

All the txt files can be accessed in one directory, or from a CSV, whatever is easiest.

Comment: This isn't that difficult, what have you tried so far? Post some code, tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: I've not long started learning - I have no idea how to reverse around the delimiter (with countless googling) without that, I really don't have much code to show. 

I can grab the files fine and do basic renaming which I've been playing around with, but not based on these rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having the exact details of your file paths, where it'll run, etc. you'll have to adapt this to point at the appropriate path(s).

```
$s= "Monday,England.txt";
#$s = "Wednesday,Spain.txt";

$nameparts = $s.split(".")[0].split(",");
if ($nameparts[1].length -gt 6) {
    $newname = $nameparts[1].substring(0,6);
} else {
    $newname = $nameparts[1];
}

if ($nameparts[0].length -gt 2) {
    $newname += $nameparts[0].substring(0,2);
} else {
    $newname += $nameparts[0];
}

$newname = $newname.toLower() + "."+ $s.split(".")[1];
$newname;

get-item $s |rename-item -NewName $newname;
```

I'm certain this isn't the most efficient/elegant way to do this, but it works with both of your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to achieve this by splitting the string into arrays in powershell and then recording the array to get your reverse.

For example:

```
$fileNameExtension = "Monday,England.txt";

$fileName = $fileNameExtension.split("."); // gets you an array [Monday,England][txt]
$fileparts = $fileName.split(","); // gets you an array [Monday][England]

//Create the new substring parts, notice you can now pull items from the array in any order you need, 
//You will need to check the length before using substringing

$part1 = $fileparts[1].substring(0,5);
$part2 = $fileparts[0].substring(0,2);

//Now construct the new file name by rebuilding the string

$newfileName = $part1 + $part2 + “.” + $fileName[1];
```

Comment: Sorry should have refreshed my page before posting an answer as you can see the answer above is more complete

Comment: You *must* check the lengths of your substrings, because calling `substring(1,6)` on a 5-character string will throw an error. Also, strings are indexed at 0, so you'll miss the first character.

Comment: Many thanks to you both. 


Is it best if I use get-childitem to pull the files, and get this to loop through them all and rename them? I wouldn't need to change the output if I set $s as the child items?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-ChildItem` to grab the files, then on files that match your criteria, use regular expressions to capture the first two characters of the day of the week and the first six characters of the location, then use those captures to create a new filename.  This is my best guess.  Use `-WhatIf` on the `Move-Item` cmdlet until you get the regular expression and the destination path correct.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Path\To\Files *.txt |
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -matches '^([^,]{2})[^,]*,(.{1,6})' } |
    Move-Item -WhatIf -Destination {
        $newFileName = '{0}{1}.txt' -f $matches[1],$matches[2]
        Join-Path C:\Path\To\Files $newFileName.ToLower()
    }
```